# dont append but overwrite log file of logger

Tags: ruby, logging, ruby-2.0

I use logger in my application and direct the output to a file like this:

```
Logger.new("nemobuild.log")
```

My logger appends to this logfile once its created.

**What i want it to do is to clear the logfile on each program start.**

In the examples is a description for creating a new logfile:

```
file = File.open('foo.log', File::WRONLY | File::APPEND | File::CREAT)
```

*What `File::` params would i have to use to get the desired behaivior?*

Comment: Add `File::TRUNC` See: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File/Constants.html

Comment: try open mode `File.open('foo.log','w')` or try to remove *APPEND* mode.

Comment: File::TRUNC didnt do it either, i ended up deleting the file before setting up the logger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up deleting the file before setting up the logger:

```
File.delete("nemobuild.log")
logger = Logger.new("nemobuild.log")
```

Answer (score 6):

Which gem do you use? Can you provide a MWE?

With
    Logger.new("nemobuild.log")

I get the error:

```
`<main>': uninitialized constant Logger (NameError)
```

---

Do you use the standard Logger?

Then you can use a file object instead a filename for the logfile:

```
require 'logger'
log = Logger.new(File.new("nemobuild.log",'w'))
log.error('XX')
```

If you want back the append-mode, you can switch the `w`-option (write) to `a` (append):

```
log = Logger.new(File.new("nemobuild.log",'a'))
```

---

Assuming you can/want use [log4r](https://rubygems.org/gems/log4r):

The feature you need is an option `trunc` of the FileOutputter:

```
require 'log4r' 

log = Log4r::Logger.new('log')
log.outputters << Log4r::FileOutputter.new(
    'log_file', :filename => 'mini_example.log', 
    :trunc => true, #Delete old log
    )
```